# Unable to install office 2021 LTSC with the .xml config file

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2021

Hello Im trying to install office 2021 LTSC following this guide from microsoft. I added our MAX code to the config file but it barfed an error saying this can only be completed in a describe block

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/ltsc2021/deploy

We will try connecting the machine to the internet as we are in an airgapped environment but any suggestions on what I could try would be gratefully accepted thanks

Comment: Being given the exact error you received would be extremely helpful